# Desktop icons shifting when external monitor is plugged in

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, icons

Whenever I plug in my external computer monitor for use with my Toshiba laptop, all of my desktop icons shift down. This started when I first plugged in the external monitor and since it isn't exactly level with my computer's screen, I had to go into System Settings to move the monitor up so windows would drag over correctly. When I changed my monitor arrangement, my desktop icons shifted down. Whenever I unplug the monitor, everything goes back to normal, but this is really irritating. Windows doesn't do this and Mac OS X doesn't do it either. Help? (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Toshiba Satellite C55-B, Dell E171FP External Monitor 1920x1280)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I connect my 2nd monitor, haven't found a solution yet but I did found a workaround, there is a package called ARandR that helps. Its in Ubuntu's repository, so to install it you only need to run the following command:

sudo apt-get install arandr

Then run it using:

arandr

Once you run the command it will open a window on which you will able to position your laptop display up and down and avoid the desktop Icons moving to any extended portion. **The Downside of this workaround is that once you unplug the 2nd monitor the desktop icons will shift to the extended portion of you laptop screen.**